# Add UISwitch to TableViewCell of style subtitle

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3, interface-builder

I need a cell that has a title, a description, and a switch on the right. I am able to program this on my own, but I'd like to take advantage of the `subtitle` cells that already have a description (`detailTextLabel`).

However, whenever I try to add a `UISwitch` in the Interface Builder, it just does not work. First, it does not let me drag the switch into the cell. When I drag it outside and then insert it in the `Content View` from the Document Outline (left sidebar), it appears to be inside, but I can not add constraints:
[image: Cell with switch inside]

I have a `SwitchCell.swift` that looks like this:

```
public class SwitchCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var switch: UISwitch!
...
}
```

I can create a link to the storyboard for the title label, not for the switch one.

Does anyone know what I have to modify in order to add an accessory label to the subtitle cell? It works with code from the controller with `cell.accessoryView.= UISwitch()`, but I'd like to know why it is not possible in the Interface Builder

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, you can't modify the built-in cell types such as "the `subtitle` cells that already have a description (`detailTextLabel`)." If you want to add a switch or make other content modifications in Interface Builder, you must use a Custom cell.

You can, however, continue to use a `subtitle` cell in Interface Builder but add and configure your switch *in code* (in `cellForRowAt:`, for example).

Comment: that is what I already did (as explained in my question). Do you happen to know why this is like this? It is not that the cell is created as non-modifiable (can be modified from program).

Comment: It's just how Interface Builder implements the built-in cell types. Mine not to reason why; I don't work for Apple. I could _guess_, but that would be silly. If you don't like it, do file an enhancement request with Apple.